# No encuentro la libreria SOAP en PHP7

Tags: php

Borre XAMPP con php 5 e instale una version mas nueva con php7.
Pero cuando voy al phpinfo(), la libreria soap no tiene un apartado. Tampoco la encuentro en el archivo de ocnfiguracion php.ini.

Alguien sabe algo? Hubo algun cambio?

Comment: cual ibrería SOAP, si buscas cambios al respecto ya fuiste a la página oficial del producto o a su github para verificarlo?

Comment: Me refiero a SOAP client y SOAP server, es decir tengo una app que se conecta a los servicios de la AFIP. Webservices y para eso requiere esa libreria habilitada

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47511800/soapclient-call-works-on-php-5-6-but-not-on-php-7

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, por eso preguntaba. obtengo este error: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in

Comment: Antes se solucionaba habilitando SOAP la libreria, en php.ini pero ahora no aparece.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno encontre la solucion:

Cambio el archivo php.ini aparentemente. Hay una linea de la siguiente forma:

```
;extension=soap
```

Se debe borra el `;` (punto y coma) y listo.-